# Android auto update EditText if others are filled

Tags: android, android-studio, android-edittext

I'm new to Android and Java programing and I'm working on my first application, but I hit a problem. 
I have three EditTexts: `FuelAmount`, `FuelCost`, `CashSpend` and what i want to achieve is - when `FA` is filled and `FC` is beeing filed, `CS` should be auto filled. 
I want that to work in all possible combinations `FA`>`FC`=`CS`, `FA`>`CS`=`FC` etc.
So I tried and find a `addTextChangedListener` to all of my `EditTexts`. But when I'm testing all ways of input the data the app crashes with

> java.lang.StackOverflowError

on combinations like when I put `FuelCost` and then `CashSpend` or `FuelAmount` and then `CashSpend`.

```
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class NewRefuelActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 

    EditText KmCounter,FuelAmount, FuelPrice,CashSpend,RefuelDate;
    Context context = this;
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;
    Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.new_refuel);

        android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar toolbar = (android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null){
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }

        KmCounter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NewRefuel_KmCounter_Input);
        FuelAmount = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NewRefuel_FuelAmount_Input);
        FuelPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NewRefuel_FuelPrice_Input);
        CashSpend = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NewRefuel_CashSpend_Input);
        RefuelDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.NewRefuel_Date_Input);

        updateLabel_RefuelDate();

        RefuelDate.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        RefuelDate.setFocusable(false);

        final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener DTPListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR,year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH,monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,dayOfMonth);
                updateLabel_RefuelDate();
            }
        };

        RefuelDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new DatePickerDialog(NewRefuelActivity.this,
                        DTPListener,
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
            }
        });

//error
    EditText_AutoFill();

    }

    public void EditText_AutoFill(){

        FuelAmount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() != 0){
                    if (FuelPrice.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0){
                        Float FA = Float.parseFloat(FuelAmount.getText().toString());
                        Float FC = Float.parseFloat(FuelPrice.getText().toString());
                        Float CS = FA * FC;

                        CashSpend.setText(CS.toString());
                    }
                    else if (CashSpend.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0){
                        Float FA = Float.parseFloat(FuelAmount.getText().toString());
                        Float CS = Float.parseFloat(CashSpend.getText().toString());
                        Float FC = CS / FA;

                        FuelAmount.setText(FC.toString());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        FuelPrice.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() != 0) {
                    if (FuelAmount.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0) {
                        Float FC = Float.parseFloat(FuelPrice.getText().toString());
                        Float FA = Float.parseFloat(FuelAmount.getText().toString());
                        Float CS = FA * FC;

                        CashSpend.setText(CS.toString());
                    } else if (CashSpend.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0) {
                        Float FC = Float.parseFloat(FuelPrice.getText().toString());
                        Float CS = Float.parseFloat(CashSpend.getText().toString());
                        Float FA = CS / FC;

                        FuelAmount.setText(FA.toString());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });

        CashSpend.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                if (s.length() != 0) {
                    if (FuelAmount.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0) {
                        Float CS = Float.parseFloat(CashSpend.getText().toString());
                        Float FA = Float.parseFloat(FuelAmount.getText().toString());
                        Float FC = CS / FA;

                        FuelPrice.setText(FC.toString());
                    } else if (FuelPrice.getText().toString().trim().length() != 0) {
                        Float CS = Float.parseFloat(CashSpend.getText().toString());
                        Float FC = Float.parseFloat(FuelPrice.getText().toString());
                        Float FA = CS / FC;

                        FuelAmount.setText(FA.toString());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void updateLabel_RefuelDate(){
        String myFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy";
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
        RefuelDate.setText(simpleDateFormat.format(myCalendar.getTime()));
    }


    public void addNewRefuel(){


        Float km_counter = Float.parseFloat(KmCounter.getText().toString());
        Float fuel_amount = Float.parseFloat(FuelAmount.getText().toString());
        Float fuel_price = Float.parseFloat(FuelPrice.getText().toString());
        Float cash_spend = Float.parseFloat(CashSpend.getText().toString());
        String fuel_date = RefuelDate.getText().toString();

        dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        sqLiteDatabase = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        dbHelper.addRefuel(fuel_amount, fuel_price, cash_spend, km_counter, fuel_date, sqLiteDatabase);

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Tankowanie dodane", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        dbHelper.close();

    }

    public void clearRefuelEditText(){
        //KmCounter.getText().clear(); 
        KmCounter.setText("");
        FuelAmount.setText("");
        FuelPrice.setText("");
        CashSpend.setText("");
        RefuelDate.setText("");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_new_refuel_activity, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_refuel_tab) {
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.action_add_refuel){
            addNewRefuel();
            clearRefuelEditText();
            finish();

            //TODO: przetestowac alternatywe finish()
            /*
            Intent i=new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
            }
            */
            return true;
        }
            case android.R.id.home:
                // this takes the user 'back', as if they pressed the left-facing triangle icon on the main android toolbar.
                // if this doesn't work as desired, another possibility is to call `finish()` here.
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

}
```

Can someone suggest me any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Edit. Entire error

```
04-22 06:28:18.280 1816-1816/? E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.StackOverflowError
                                                   at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:77)
                                                   at android.text.method.ReplacementTransformationMethod$ReplacementCharSequence.getChars(ReplacementTransformationMethod.java:151)
                                                   at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:77)
                                                   at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1800)
                                                   at android.text.TextLine.handleText(TextLine.java:747)
                                                   at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:956)
                                                   at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:414)
                                                   at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:293)
                                                   at android.text.TextLine.metrics(TextLine.java:267)
                                                   at android.text.Layout.getLineExtent(Layout.java:998)
                                                   at android.text.Layout.getLineStartPos(Layout.java:504)
                                                   at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:861)
                                                   at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:830)
                                                   at android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(Layout.java:805)
                                                   at android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(Layout.java:795)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.getFocusedRect(TextView.java:5135)
                                                   at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:120)
                                                   at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:94)
                                                   at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:65)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:670)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:672)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:672)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:672)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:672)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:672)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:672)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:672)
                                                   at android.view.View.focusSearch(View.java:6392)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.onCreateInputConnection(TextView.java:5641)
                                                   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:1120)
                                                   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.restartInput(InputMethodManager.java:1070)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3691)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3629)
                                                   at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3604)
                                                   at com.example.pietrzyk.sqlite1.NewRefuelActivity$5.onTextChanged(NewRefuelActivity.java:162)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7318)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3774)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3629)
                                                   at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3604)
                                                   at com.example.pietrzyk.sqlite1.NewRefuelActivity$4.onTextChanged(NewRefuelActivity.java:130)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7318)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3774)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3629)
                                                   at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3604)
                                                   at com.example.pietrzyk.sqlite1.NewRefuelActivity$5.onTextChanged(NewRefuelActivity.java:162)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7318)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3774)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3629)
                                                   at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3604)
                                                   at com.example.pietrzyk.sqlite1.NewRefuelActivity$4.onTextChanged(NewRefuelActivity.java:130)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7318)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3774)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3629)
                                                   at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3604)
                                                   at com.example.pietrzyk.sqlite1.NewRefuelActivity$5.onTextChanged(NewRefuelActivity.java:162)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7318)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3774)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3629)04-22 06:28:18.280 1816-1816/? E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.StackOverflowError
                                                   at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:77)
                                                   at android.text.method.ReplacementTransformationMethod$ReplacementCharSequence.getChars(ReplacementTransformationMethod.java:151)
                                                   at android.text.TextUtils.getChars(TextUtils.java:77)
                                                   at android.graphics.Paint.getTextRunAdvances(Paint.java:1800)
                                                   at android.text.TextLine.handleText(TextLine.java:747)
                                                   at android.text.TextLine.handleRun(TextLine.java:956)
                                                   at android.text.TextLine.measureRun(TextLine.java:414)
                                                   at android.text.TextLine.measure(TextLine.java:293)
                                                   at android.text.TextLine.metrics(TextLine.java:267)
                                                   at android.text.Layout.getLineExtent(Layout.java:998)
                                                   at android.text.Layout.getLineStartPos(Layout.java:504)
                                                   at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:861)
                                                   at android.text.Layout.getHorizontal(Layout.java:830)
                                                   at android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(Layout.java:805)
                                                   at android.text.Layout.getPrimaryHorizontal(Layout.java:795)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.getFocusedRect(TextView.java:5135)
                                                   at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:120)
                                                   at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:94)
                                                   at android.view.FocusFinder.findNextFocus(FocusFinder.java:65)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:670)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:672)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:672)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:672)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:672)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:672)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:672)
                                                   at android.view.ViewGroup.focusSearch(ViewGroup.java:672)
                                                   at android.view.View.focusSearch(View.java:6392)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.onCreateInputConnection(TextView.java:5641)
                                                   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner(InputMethodManager.java:1120)
                                                   at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.restartInput(InputMethodManager.java:1070)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3691)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3629)
                                                   at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3604)
                                                   at com.example.pietrzyk.sqlite1.NewRefuelActivity$5.onTextChanged(NewRefuelActivity.java:162)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7318)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3774)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3629)
                                                   at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3604)
                                                   at com.example.pietrzyk.sqlite1.NewRefuelActivity$4.onTextChanged(NewRefuelActivity.java:130)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7318)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3774)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3629)
                                                   at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3604)
                                                   at com.example.pietrzyk.sqlite1.NewRefuelActivity$5.onTextChanged(NewRefuelActivity.java:162)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7318)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3774)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3629)
                                                   at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3604)
                                                   at com.example.pietrzyk.sqlite1.NewRefuelActivity$4.onTextChanged(NewRefuelActivity.java:130)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7318)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3774)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3629)
                                                   at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3604)
                                                   at com.example.pietrzyk.sqlite1.NewRefuelActivity$5.onTextChanged(NewRefuelActivity.java:162)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7318)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3774)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3629)
```

Comment: Please post the (full) error.

Comment: well it works fine on my emulator.. can you post whole code?

Comment: Whole activity code added. Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

There are few things which you have to keep in mind:

1. `EditText` which you are using can also contains spaces which may also lead to crash. To avoid that rather than taking `editText.length()` its better to take `editText.getText().toString().trim().length()`.
2. Secondly, make sure that in that layout you should constrain the user to enter only numbers for which you have to set attribute `android:inputType="number"`.

Comment: All my EditText's uses android:inputType="numberDecimal". Also I fallowed your suggestion and replaced lenght() with getText().toString().trim().length() - but it didnt helped, still app crashes.

Comment: can u post the error so that I can help you with that

Comment: Error added in main post at the bottom.

Comment: https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/exceptions/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-how-to-solve-stackoverflowerror/ check this link it might help you

Comment: at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3774)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3629)
                                                   at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:80)
                                                   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3604) this are line of repeating  so check those lines

Comment: I am trying to find where my stack is going wrong but I cannot find a solution. Error msg says that error take places while every single .setText() method is called in my app ( like CashSpend.setText(CS.toString()); )